# How can I configure spring app to use IAM Role(running inside AWS ECS) on aws and credentials on dev env?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

How to configure spring boot app to use IAM Role? Is this code below enough? Or I'm totally wrong?

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {

    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance(), new ProfileCredentialsProvider()))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: In my experience you can usually use a preconfigured chain..  the doc can be a bit confusing on that front.

Comment: Do yo have some example of preconfigured chain?

Comment: Add your language tag and we'll see what we can do

Answer (score 3):

Use STSAssumeRole to achive this

```
    @Value("${my.aws.assumeRoleARN:}")
    private String assumeRoleARN;    

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        log.info("Assuming role {}",assumeRoleARN);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(assumeRoleARN)) {
            AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration())
                    .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                    .build();

            return new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider
                    .Builder(assumeRoleARN, "role")
                    .withStsClient(stsClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return awsCredentialsProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.configuration")
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return new ClientConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().
                withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider()).
                withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration()).
                build();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell how you created awsCredentialsProvider which you have passed while creating  AWSSecurityTokenService bean @Ram

Comment: you can just do     @Autowired   private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider; . Their will be a default awsCredentialsProvider bean already created by spring cloud

Comment: Thanks @Ram. I have used  InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This code is not working now.

Answer (score 1):

I did as below and its working fine, dont use InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance() which is not working with me

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
  return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
      .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1).build();
}
```