# SpringBoot service is not using the IAM role mapped on service account in helm deployment

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

I have a SpringBoot service deployed on the Kubernetes and the service uses helm for the resources. The problem I have is, my SpringBoot service is not able to connect to S3 and I keep getting the exception.

```
Request processing failed: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 159XV34YG8240R7W; S3 Extended Request ID: blah; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: blah
```

I can see on the pod that `AWS_ROLE_ARN` and `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE` environment variables are set correctly. The serviceaccount `yaml` has the role set as

```
eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my-role"
```

and the service account is correctly mapped on the deployment `yaml` file.

My IAM role has the correct trust relationship for `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` to allow my serviceaccount deployed on my namespace and has full access to S3 for all resources.

Is there something I am missing? Or is it very much necessary to use the `STSAssumeRole` again on the service like as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58660592/1036310)?

Answer (score 0):

1. There needs to be permissions in two sides:

- Role 1: The receiving role, the role you're assuming to which "trusts" your a different IAM role attached to  your Service Account.
- Role 2: That IAM role being able to perform the `sts:assumeRole` action.

2. For that, you'll need to have an `IAM OIDC provider for your cluster`, create it in the AWS console, and describe it doing something like this:

`aws eks describe-cluster --name MYCLUSTER --query "cluster.identity.oidc.issuer" --output text`

3. Create that IAM role (Role 2), which should have `sts:assumeRole` to your other role that has s3 perms.
4. Edit your k8 service account, and add an annotation to it with the role that has sts perms (role 2)
5. Any `pod` using that service account should now successfully be able to "hop" or `sts assume-role` into your s3 role (role 1)

Here's some more information from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/associate-service-account-role.html